# Will a mother praying mantis stay with the egg sack?

Tags: entomology

We caught a pregnant praying mantis (without knowing it was pregnant). It made an egg sack on the underside of a cardboard bridge in its container.

It is in Pasadena, California. It kind of looks like the one in [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stagmomantis_limbata), except that it is paler green color (kind of tan brown/green). In the past I have seen some with red eyes, but I think this one had eyes that were black. I'm not sure if the eye color changes in the light, though.

Not knowing how to care for babies, we left the container outside in the shade with an open lid (so that the mother can climb out any time she wants, and so can the babies when they hatch). The mother climbed out immediately but remained on the outside wall of the container (near the egg sack) for hours.  However, the mother is no longer there.  Is it normal for a mother to abandon the egg sack?  Can we expect the mother to return?

Comment: Do you know what species of mantis — this matters because some species do provide care but most don't ...

Comment: @tyersome : I had responded to your question, and now I find that someone removed it from the comments and put my response in the question itself (which makes sense, except you may not notice it). I likely also forgot to @ you in my comment, so I am doing that now (in case my added info is helpful).